# How to fix the error "Selection.addRange()"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I need help to fix this error :

> The behavior that Selection.addRange() merges existing Range and the
>   specified Range is deprecated and will be removed in M58, around April
>   2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6680566019653632 for more details.

I can't edit, or destroy element of my website.

Answer (score 3):

From [this Github issue](https://github.com/codekraft-studio/angular-content-editable/issues/8), now you have to call [`removeAllRanges()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Selection/removeAllRanges) before adding a range to your selection:

```
selection = window.getSelection();    // Save the selection.
range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(elem);
selection.removeAllRanges();          // Remove all ranges from the selection.
selection.addRange(range);            // Add the new range.
```